# how can I change values from a nested list accordingly?

Tags: python-3.x

I am making a game which requires me to randomly select 2 buildings from a pool of different buildings, and after choosing 1 of the 2 buildings the count from the building pool will be deducted. I am having troubles changing the values of the selected items in the nested loop. Is there any way I can change it? This is my current code:

`building_list = [['house', 8], ['hospital', 8], ['shopping-center', 8], ['airport', 8], ['park', 8]]`

`building_list1 = random.choice(building_list)[0]`

`building_list2 = random.choice(building_list)[0]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have concern about the performance of removing the "chosen" building, then I will propose different approach to this problem.  The reason is that to constant search and remove list item is not efficient.

Please let me know if you have question.

```
n = 2      # select 2 buildings to pop

while n:   # n is not zero: means it's True
    random.shuffle(building_list)
    building_pop = building_list.pop()  # remove last item from list is O(1)
    print(build_pop)
    # do whatever you want to this two building here <----
    
    n -= 1
```

Answer (score 1):

this looks complex but basically we are finding what the random item was then decrementing its value by 1 then getting the name of the building.

```
import random

building_list = [['house', 8], ['hospital', 8], ['shopping-center', 8], 
['airport', 8], ['park', 8]]

building1 = random.choice(building_list)

building_list[building_list.index(building1)][1] -= 1

building_list1 = building1[0]

print(building1)
print(building_list1)

building2 = random.choice(building_list)

building_list[building_list.index(building2)][1] -= 1

building_list2 = building2[0]

print(building2)
print(building_list2)
```

I got this output:

```
['shopping-center', 7]
shopping-center
['hospital', 7]
hospital
```

Comment: This will not be efficient - if the list is big and performance is important.

Comment: @Daniel Hao I don't see how.
I'm not that good at list stuff but if this helps anyone please upvote